# Como pegar o valor de uma célula com referência dinâmica

Tags: microsoft-excel

Por exemplo:

Na célula `A1` conterá um número, que será a linha a ser considerada.

Na célula `A2` preciso uma função para que mostre o valor de uma célula conforme digitada na `A1`, algo do tipo `=B"A1"`.

Conforme exemplo, suponhamos que o valor de `A1` seja `2`, a célula deve mostrar o valor de `B2`. Se o valor de `A1` for `3`, deverá mostrar o valor de `B3`.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: @dot.Py não vejo a necessidade da tag citada, uma vez que ela nem existe aqui e que a tag excel já abrange que seja um problema de formula, pois se for vba, terá esta tag tambem.

Comment: @diegofm bom, ok então! agradeço a sua atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri por acaso fuçando nas funções do Excel

`=INDIRETO("B"&A1)`